# Juntar valores espalhados em diferentes linhas em uma mesma linha

Tags: r

Olá,

tenho um banco de dados em que eu usei o tidyr::spread o que resultou em uma informação espalhada por várias linhas. Gostaria de juntar as diferentes linhas em uma só. Exemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(obs = c(1,1,1,2),
                 msgA = c("A", NA, NA, "A" ),
                 msgB = c(NA,"B",NA, NA),
                 msgC = c(NA,NA,"C", NA))

#O que eu tentei:

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(obs) %>%
  mutate(msg = paste(msgA, msgB, msgC, sep=", ")) %>%
  select(-c(2:4))

# Resultado que eu queria:
# 
# > df
# obs     msg
# 1     A, B, C
# 2       A
```

Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) tem a função `unite()` que pode servir para isso.

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::unite(msg, msgA:msgC, sep = ", ")
  obs       msg
1   1 A, NA, NA
2   1 NA, B, NA
3   1 NA, NA, C
4   2 A, NA, NA
```

Ocorre que a `unite()` está pensada para [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) *tidy*, então o resultado que ela gera não é bem o que tu querias.

Para gera o resultado esperado é melhor usar o `data.frame` antes do `spread()` e usar `group_by()` combinado com `summarise()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
tidy <- df %>% 
  gather(tipo, msg, -obs) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(msg))

tidy %>% 
  group_by(obs) %>% 
  summarise(msg = paste(msg, collapse = ", "))
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##     obs msg    
##   <dbl> <chr>  
## 1     1 A, B, C
## 2     2 A
```